# Created a page in WordPress to accept query parameters and show me data

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this website:

`http://sub.example.com/vin-number-details/`

Now I want to pass a parameter to it like this:

`http://sub.example.com/vin-number-details?name=1FT7W2B64GEA17729`

I had added the following code in my functions.php file inside my theme folder:

```
    <?php 
    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'addnew_query_vars', 10, 1 );
    function addnew_query_vars($vars)
    {   
        $vars[] = 'var1';  
        return $vars;
    }
 other code of theme goes below
```

The PHP code has this value, ised the PHP snippets to create a snippet and paste it in visual editor like this:

```
<?php
    // example code
    $welcome = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/decodevin/$_GET['var1']?format=json'), true);

    echo "<span style='font-size:16px;color:green;'>Results for: ".'<strong>'.$welcome['SearchCriteria'].'</strong></span><p>&nbsp;</p>';
    if(!empty($welcome)){
        echo '<table class="table"><tbody>';
        foreach($welcome['Results'] as $val){
        echo '<tr><th scope="row" width="30%">'.'#'.$val['VariableId'].'</th><td>'.$val['Variable'].'</td><td>'.$val['Value'].'</td></tr>';
        }
     echo '</tbody></table>';
    }
?>
```

Used in page as:

```
[xyz-ips snippet="VinDecoder"]
```

But I am always seeing 404 error and not able to p[ass the name parameter to this script so it can work and show me the details

Comment: Why are you passing a VIN as `name`? Just `vin` would be more appropriate. Variable names should always reflect what they represent. They certainly *should not* reflect something that they definitely are not, particularly when that's easily confused with something else.

Comment: like this http://sub.example.com/vin-number-details/?1FT7W2B64GEA17729

Comment: i tried the change you suggested by removing code but i see empty page and when i called the website online, i see the json response: https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/decodevin/1FT7W2B64GEA17729?format=json, i am not sure what i am doing wrong here